# How to record network throughput per port for long period of time

Tags: networking, monitoring

I have come across `vnstat` recently, and am enjoying it's simplicity, low resource usage, and its ability to record network history long term.

However, I am looking for a similar tool (for long term archival history), which can record the amount of traffic through network ports.

Ultimately, I'd like to be able to view the data in a way that shows me:

- most used TCP/UDP port (e.g. Ports sorted by most bytes TX, or RX)
- most used TCP/UDP port (e.g. Ports sorted by most number of packets)
- amount of bytes and/or packets transmitted on that port over "X" period of time (days, months, hours)
- ability to exclude certain ports (e.g. http:80)

I would prefer a non-GUI tool. Wireshark and similar are too bulky for my needs.

---

Progs I've tried

- bandwidthd
- bmon
- bwm, bwm-ng
- dstat
- ifstat
- ifstatus
- iftop
- iperf/netperf/uperf
- iptrack
- nethogs
- nload
- strobe
- tcptrack

Comment: What's wrong with the programs you've listed so far?

Comment: They don't record long term stats, or they don't show breakdown by TCP/UDP ports, or they don't show stats based on hosts. These tools lack one or two of the features I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Darkstat](http://unix4lyfe.org/darkstat/) serves my purposes nicely. However, I have found that version 3.0.715 works better than 3.0.717.